# Display side panel inline on minimized window

Tags: html, css

I need to make my side panel in an web application more responsive. I've searched for help on google but it doesn't answer my question. I have a side panel on my site where the content is stacked in full desktop display (which I want). But on minimizing it stays stackt on top of each other, I want it to change to inline instead. See my pictures for a visual example of what I want to achieve.

How it looks in desktop mode, as I want.
[image: https://imgur.com/a/acLtMT9]

When minimizing window, How I don't want it to be:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/DlXFXXU]

How I want it do be:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/8cmB8Ok]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use media query for target the view in which you want it to set inline and set `display:inline-block` to your element.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abhineetV/e8d73s26/3/)

for example:

```
.stack_nav{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  list-style: none;
}
.stack_nav>li{
  padding: 10px;
  display:block;
}

@media (max-width: 767px){
  .stack_nav>li{
     display: inline-block; 
  }  
}
```